# match column "A" to "D" and use Column "B" id and place it in front of the matching value on "D"

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to Excel and VBA.

Column "A" has an ID listed on "B" and column C has the total list not included on "A" what I am trying to do is (`if "A"="C`) then use the ID from "B" and place it/copy in front of "D"

```
=INDEX(B2,MATCH(A2,C2))
```

I am thinking to create a macro where I can just copy the list of test to another sheet then match the values, as column "A" and "C" are not the same then copy the value from "B" to "D" if "A" is found on "C"
I have more than 2500 values that will be part of column "C" but column "A" will never have the same number of rows as "C"
I know it looks simple from the screenshot but the naming convention is different.

I hope it make sense what I am trying to explain here. if not please let me know
[image: Screenshot of Excel sheet]

Comment: so the pink rows are where the id should be repeated and the others leave column D blank?

Comment: that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "IF" logic can be captured by the IF function. So you put this formula in D2 and drag it down as far as you wish.

```
=if(A2=C2,B2,"")
```

Revision: The above would work if the match were to be checked for in the same row. But I now understand we are supposed to look in the entire column A. In that case, we can do the following in D2 and drag,

```
=iferror(indirect(address(1+match(C2,A$2:A,0),2)),"")
```

The iferror lets the thing stay empty if match fails. If match succeeds, 1+match is the row, and 2 is column B. We make an address of that and find what is at that address.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, but this is not an option as the lists are not a 1 to 1 match. meaning if A is 300 total rows and C is 2600 I need to find the matching row. so lets say "A300" is the same as "C1400" if I do 1 to 1 matching then it is not going to be equal

Comment: Oh, because I thought that's what the pinks in the example were showing. So let me try to restate this better. I read the value in column C. Then I look down the whole A column for a match. If I find one, I put  its neighbor from column B next to the current C row I'm looking at, in column D.  What if I find more than one match? Take the first? (Should never happen?)

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, this is just what I was looking for.